# Black box appears in corner of object in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My program was working as usual before I tried to increase the size of my rotating circle. This caused a black box to appear in the top left corner of the circle, which rotates together with the circle. The dimensions of the box change depending on the circles location on the display.

Here is an image of the problem:
[image: Image of what happens when i run the code]

And my code:

```py
import pygame
from math import sin, cos

pygame.init

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((450, 650))

circle = pygame.image.load("filer/circle.png").convert_alpha()
circle = pygame.transform.scale(circle, (160, 160))
circle_rect = circle.get_rect()
circle_rect.center = (225, 225)

pen = pygame.image.load("filer/knife2.png").convert_alpha()
pen = pygame.transform.scale(pen, (60, 80))
pen = pygame.transform.rotate(pen, 180)
pen_rect = pen.get_rect()
pen_rect.center = (300, 300)

background = pygame.image.load("filer/landscape.jpeg")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (800, 650))

# funcation that rotates the surface for set angle
def rotate_surface(surface, x, y, angle):
    # creates a new surface so it stops it from glitching
    rotated_surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, -angle)

    rect = rotated_surface.get_rect(center=(x, y))

    return rotated_surface, rect


knife_rect = []
angle_bane_l = []
angle_rot_l = []


def knife_movement(knife_rect, angle_bane, angle_rot):
    for i in range(len(knife_rect)):
        x = i - 1
        # updates angles for each loop
        angle_bane[x] += 0.057
        angle_rot[x] += 1 * rot_ratio + 0.273

        # calculates the position of the knife around the circle
        knife_rect[x].x = cos(angle_bane_l[x]) * 100 + 225
        knife_rect[x].y = sin(angle_bane_l[x]) * 100 + 225

        # rotates pen so it always faces circle
        rotated_pen, knife_rect[x] = rotate_surface(
            pen, knife_rect[x].x, knife_rect[x].y, angle_rot[x]
        )

        screen.blit(rotated_pen, knife_rect[x])


rot_ratio = 3
c_angle_rot = 0
k_angle_around = 1.54
k_angle_rot = 84.89

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print("space")
                # creates a new knife and places it at bottom of circle
                angle_bane_l.append(1.54)
                angle_rot_l.append(84.89)
                knife_rect.append(pen.get_rect())

    # makes all knives rotate around circle
    knife_movement(knife_rect, angle_bane_l, angle_rot_l)

    pygame.draw.rect(circle, (0, 0, 0), circle_rect)

    # function to rotate circle
    rotated_circle, circle_rect = rotate_surface(circle, 225, 225, c_angle_rot)

    screen.blit(rotated_circle, circle_rect)

    c_angle_rot += 1 * rot_ratio

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You're drawing the black rectangle on the circle with `pygame.draw.rect(circle, (0,0,0),circle_rect)`

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing the black rectangle on the circle with `pygame.draw.rect(circle, (0,0,0),circle_rect)`